# python neurolab - Can we train incrementally with many input parts?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am using the neurolab for Machine learning classfication problem,
Link :- http://code.google.com/p/neurolab/

My question is, can we train the neural network incrementally ?

To explain further, I have three parts of input data, I want to train the Neuro Net by

```
e = net.train(input_part1, output_part1, show=1, epochs=100, goal=0.0001)
e = net.train(input_part2, output_part2, show=1, epochs=100, goal=0.0001)
e = net.train(input_part3, output_part3, show=1, epochs=100, goal=0.0001)
```

will the train call with first two parts will be effective in predicting the 
neural net parameters -OR- Will this use only last training data ?

Comment: Why not to use one of mainstream libraries? Scikit-learn, Keras, PyTorch, etc... many of them have an explicit model instance and ability to train it weights incrementaly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you will add all data together into one dataset and train the net on this training set. Training refers to setting the weights. Why not add all inputs (part1, part2, part3) into one dataset? Note, that there are techniques where learning and re-adjusting is part of the learning algorithm. If you want to do a plain algorithm you have one cycle of training and one cycle of performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I can merge all parts of inputs. But the problem is individual parts itself very huge, so i am afraid that after merging them even i cannot load the data for training.. If there is a way please help me ?

Comment: How big are the files? You could merge the files. If you want to add the weights for each training set, that is going to be difficult. You could output the weights and look if the problem is additive? Have you tried the testing data, using only one part? If you are going to use Gigabytes of samples, I'm not sure this will work. Is this text? By the way, it is netiquette at stackoverflow to accept answers for questions if you can. Cheers.

Comment: It seems, the data size is your actual problem. You could use numpy.memmap. It simulates an array in memory, but the data actually remains on disk.